# Font is abstract ; Cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, fonts

Im trying to make some text bold in a JTable with

```
jtable.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
```

However its throwing an error saying **"Font is abstract ; Cannot be instantiated"**

Im literally following a tutorial and its saying it should work

What else in my program could be affecting it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not importing `java.awt.Font` but another `Font` class.

The constructor for `java.awt.Font` should allow your initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much. Live and learn.